# Filling missing vector in R with the values based on the indicator zero and one

Tags: r

I have an vector r of length n with zeros and ones. It can't be all zero. Also I would have a vector y of length n as well but some value in y are missing based on the value zero in vector r. I have to replace the missing values in y by sample value

example if `r = c(1,1,0)` the `y = c(3,2,NA)` so sample one value (8) then replace NA with 8. the vector `r` could have two zeros so I have to sample two values. and replace the two missing of y by the sample values.

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: The sample part is not clear.  Do you have another vector from which to sample

Comment: Why do you need `r` at all? `ind <- is.na(y)` and replace with `y[ind] <- sample(1:10, sum(ind), replace = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `r` vector to booleans with `as.logical` and then use that to index into the `y` vector for the replacement. Specify the `size` argument of `sample` with the sum of the index vector for cases where there is more than one missing value. I'm sampling integers from 1:10 to illustrate this as you didn't specify what you're sampling from:

```
r <- c(1,1,0)
y <- c(3,2,NA)
idx <- !as.logical(r)
y[idx] <- sample(1:10, size = sum(idx))
```

The `r` vector is kind of redundant though as you could check for `NA` values in `y` directly:

```
ifelse(is.na(y), sample(1:10), y)
```